# What is meant by the term " intermediate application" in wcf service

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

What is meant by the term " intermediate application" in  this sentence : Use transport security when you are sending a message directly from your application to a WCF service and the message will not be routed through intermediate systems.

Comment: Just what it sounds like.  An intermediate application would be anything between the client and the service.  As I understand it, transport security is point to point - so if you go from A to B, you can use transport security for the service.  But if you're going from A to C and then to B, you can't.

Comment: Thanks for your answering.. but can you give me some example of intermediate system and application???

Comment: You can have for example Service Broker, which redirects requests based on SoapAction or content. You can have some gateways from or to external world from your intranet. You can have integration servers like BizTalk.